# Can polarity be reversed to effectively reverse the output of its intended/motored function?

Tags: power-supply, power

For "simple" electric items/tools with motors -- ones without complex electronics -- can the polarity be reversed to effectively reverse the output of its motor? In particular, I'm wondering about an electric duster:

[http://www.amazon.com/Metro-Vacuum-ED500-500-Watt-Electric/dp/B001J4ZOAW/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001J4ZOAW)

It's a high-powered blower duster, however, I've wondered about the possibility of reversing its polarity to essentially have it double as a handheld "vacuum".

In general, could this be done, and if so, is it a simple matter of reversing the polarity or would it not be a simple "backwards==forwards" matter?

Comment: Reversing polarity would reverse a DC motor, not AC.

Comment: I would guess that sort of device has a 'fan' which is not an impeller design (bladed propellor looking), but is more likely a blower (squirrel-cage looking). A blower is going to be a blower no matter which way you spin it (although more efficient in one direction than the other).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the type of motor.

For a permanent magnet DC motor swapping the wires will reverse the direction. However that is unlikely to be what you are dealing with in a simple mains powered device.

For a "universal motor" or a DC motor with electromagnetic armeture you would have to swap the wires of the field but not the armature or the armature without the field. This may or may not be tricky depending on the physical constructrution

For AC induction and synchronous motors there may be a way to do it by rearranging windings and/or capacitors but the exact procedure needed will depend heavilly on the details of the motor.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a brushed 'universal' motor you could probably rewire the field vs. armature to reverse it.

However, a vacuum needs a filter so that you don't suck crud through the impeller. I guess you could supply a filter externally, but it seems a bit cumbersome.